# Fetch rows based on value

Tags: java, sql

I have a value abc stored in string I like below -

```
String i='abc'
```

I want to fetch all rows from database which has value abc buy using below query-

```
Select * from db where docname=i;
```

I don't want to put 'abc' directly. Is there a way to do it?

Note:- I am writing this query in Java eclipse

Comment: Don't tagged conflicting RDBMS; MySQL and SQL Server are *completely* different products. As for the problem, what you want is called parametrisation. A search of this will give you a wealth of solutions.

Comment: Use `PreparedStatement`